# Flo-well dry well pipe size

Tags: drainage, sump-pump, well

This weekend I’m going to install a flo-well dry well from my basement sump outside into my yard… question is I know the flo wants 4” pipe into it but is it best to run a full 4” the whole way or should I go smaller for the majority of the run and then convert to 4” before going into the flo-well?

Comment: what is the vertical hight from pump to horizontal run ? using smaller pipe will increase the pressure and decrease the flow. What is the total distance from the pump

Comment: is there a pump, or are you on a hill?

Comment: Indeed - are you pumping water out of your sump to the dry well, or are you connecting your sump to the dry well without a pump in favorable terrain?